# Size of an object from a distance of the camera

Tags: dimensions

In my example, I have set up a canvas 500 x 500 pixels, and scaled my object to fit in the camera boundaries. Once exported to Photoshop I can see it's the correct size I wanted to export my object.
But is there a way knowing the dimensions of the object in Pixels (if there's an add-on) since it's away
from the camera boundaries. I can see the dimension of the object in Metres, but the conversion of metres to pixels is confusing. So if there's a way to see pixels when sizing and object that would be great.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Related: [constrain object size to camera angle of view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/can-i-constrain-an-object-size-to-camera-angle-of-view) and [Create a plane that always fits the camera viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13692/create-a-plane-that-always-fits-the-camera-viewport) and [fit an image in the compositor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111176/image-in-compositor-is-rendering-white-or-just-a-small-portion-of-the-original/111184#111184)

Answer (score 3):

**Notes towards an answer**.

The size of the final output image (in pixels) depends on the resolution settings for the project.

There is no default size for pixels when images are used as textures, the size of the image depends on the dimensions of the object, and how the textures are mapped as part of the material.

The size of objects in the camera view depends on three different variables:

- The dimensions of the object.
- The camera lens (or field of view in degrees).
- The distance between the object and camera.

**Answer.**

With the information above you can then use Trigonometry(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) to calculate camera placement, or lens size, or the dimensions of the object so that the image fills the screen.

[image]

[image]

**End of answer**.

---

For a lazy way to have an image fill the screen read on:

When you import an "image as plane" you can determine the size. By default blender will import an image as a plane that measures 1 unit in height.

[image]

But if you open the settings, by pressing <kbd>N</kbd> or pressing the gear icon on the top right, you can change the settings to **Camera Relative**.

That will allow you choose to have the image be at a scale that fills the current camera view. Select Fill or Fit.

[image]

**Fill** will fill the camera frame. (if the image is a different aspect ratio than that of the camera then the image might spill out of the frame)

**Fit** will fit the entire image within the camera frame (if the image is a different aspect ratio than that of the camera the image will have some empty space around it)

If the camera view and the images are the same aspect ratio, then you can use either one of those choices.

Comment: Great information, lots of insight with this explanation, it's going to surely help me with my school projects. Thanks heaps for this!!!